# Can't Import project - Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android-studio

I have tried to import some project located in a folder unzipped to my desktop.
I have tried this with "import project" (from the starting menu of android studio), but all the green icons I have tried lead me to success, and eventually no java files (with all the activities) are missed.

[image]

Comment: it is oky!!!what is your problem?

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi can't see the classes...activities....

Comment: open package under java...or change structure from project to android in top of

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi it doesn't work.....

Comment: it runs on emulator???